# Grails with ObjectDB

Tags: grails, orm, objectdb

Is it possible to use ObjectDB with Grails? 
Or in other words, do I have to use Hibernate when i developing applications with grails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible.

simply add library to your grails project and use like in java but in my option hibernate in full stack for all simpl

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, but what I meant is that I still want to use the annotation less auto generated groovy models, but to do so using ObjectDB as the backend DB

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.
I think if you do well formed configuration it works nice